# Download Remote File to Server with PHP

Tags: php, file, download

I've been looking all over the place for the last two days and trying everything and still can't get anything to work.  I feel like this should be a relatively simple thing to do.

All I want to do is download a remote file from a URL to a directory on my server.

So, for example, if

```
$_url = http://www.freewarelovers.com/android/download/temp/1306495040_Number_Blink_1.1.1.apk
```

and `$_dir = /www/downloads/`

Then when all is said and done I want `1306495040_Number_Blink_1.1.1.apk` in `/www/downloads/`

I've tried the `copy()` function, I've tried

```
file_put_contents("$_dir.$_file_name", file_get_contents($_url));
```

and get the following error:

`file_get_contents(): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!`

Comment: what about if you tell us which are the errors?

Comment: It isn't giving me any errors that's the problem..  And I feel like the question is already very clear without the additional detail I put.  I really didn't even need to tell you what I already tried I just want a solution

Comment: What errors are you getting with `file_get_contents`? Also, if you have access to the `curl` module, you can try that too.

Comment: I have `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `display_errors = On`

Comment: it's impossible that it doenst' work and it doenst' give any errors

Comment: I'm getting `file_get_contents(): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!`

Comment: doh! you said there were no errors. -1

Comment: This is a new error.  I've been trying new things since posting this.  You are the least helpful person I've ever seen on stackoverflow

Comment: What did you change that started causing the error? You're not exactly being the most helpful question asker ever, yourself.

Comment: Does it really matter what I changed?  I keep changing and trying new things, I am not going to post every little change I try that doesn't work. You know I am trying to use `file_get_contents():` and you know the error I'm getting.  I think that should be enough to work with assuming you know PHP.  I don't, which is why I'm here.

Comment: If you don't know PHP then how can you assume what details are and are not relevant?

Comment: I just don't know what that error means.  Someone familiar with HTML and PHP most likely would.  I've never seen so many condescending people in one place before

Comment: "Does it really matter what I changed?" YES! If you change something and it starts acting differently, that's **hugely** important info to have for troubleshooting purposes.

Comment: All I changed was `$_dir.$_file_name`. The same thing I changed in my post.  Still not sure how that helps you tell me what `failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!` means

Comment: I am not acting arrogant you guys just aren't helping and it's frustrating.  You are spending a lot of time pointing out irrelevant mistakes I made in my question and not a lot of time actually trying to help. I still have no idea what `failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!` means. If you weren't so condescending I would not have been so "arrogant"

Comment: All I needed was this line to get rid of the error `ini_set ('user_agent', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);`  Thanks for all the "help"

Comment: @yes123, once again, try to [be nice](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#benice). Thanks!

Comment: @Corey How, exactly, could we be expected to solve a problem in code we never saw?

Answer (score 22):

This should do it :

```
set_time_limit(0);

$url = 'http://www.freewarelovers.com/android/download/temp/1306495040_Number_Blink_1.1.1.apk';
$file = fopen(dirname(__FILE__) . '/downloads/a.apk', 'w+');

$curl = curl_init();

// Update as of PHP 5.4 array() can be written []
curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
//  CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER => 1, --- No effect from PHP 5.1.3
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_FILE           => $file,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 50,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)'
]);

$response = curl_exec($curl);

if($response === false) {
    // Update as of PHP 5.3 use of Namespaces Exception() becomes \Exception()
    throw new \Exception('Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl));
}

$response; // Do something with the response.
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the first helpful comment I've gotten.  Unfortunately I'm still having the same problem.  It doesn't look like I'm getting the whole file (only about 4 KB out of the 139 KB). And there are no errors in the `error.log`.

Comment: I don't think it's that.  Timeout is set for 60 seconds and the entire page is opening way faster than that. Any other idea what is could be?

Comment: add this : `set_time_limit(0); ini_set('display_errors',true);` at the beginning

Comment: Nope. Still no errors and it is actually 0 B not 4 KB.  I was accidentally looking at the size of the directory.  So the file isn't downloading at all and I still don't see any errors.

Comment: I really appreciate all the help; unfortunately I still can't get it working with the link I'm trying.  I'm just curious, have you gotten it to work with this link `http://www.freewarelovers.com/android/download/temp/1306495040_Number_Blink_1.1.1.apk`

Comment: It now looks like I'm only getting 20KB

Comment: Since you added an update for PHP5.4, I figure you could remove the `CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER` line as it has no effect. `From PHP 5.1.3, this option has no effect: the raw output will always be returned when CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER is used.` [http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

Comment: If you do `curl_init($url)` then you don't need to also set `CURLOPT_URL`. Or if you prefer to set it in the option array, then you can just do `curl_init()` instead. It's not necessary to do both.

Comment: Thank you, i proccess files with success.

Answer (score 17):

```
$url  = 'http://www.example.com/a-large-file.zip';
$path = '/path/to/a-large-file.zip';

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$data = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

file_put_contents($path, $data);
```

it uses curl

$url  is the file url

$path is where and the name to save the file

i hope it works

Answer (score 7):

**Since PHP 5.1.0, file_put_contents() supports writing piece-by-piece by passing a stream-handle as the $data parameter:** 
No need to use Curl

```
file_put_contents("Tmpfile.zip", fopen("http://someurl/file.zip", 'r'));
```

Comment: This is the best solution of all 

curl unnecessarily builds up your memory. When you try to build large files you will certainly get error.

Answer (score 5):

Use curl to download file from remote server like below.

```
$url = "http://path/toserver/filename";
$destination = "uploads/filename";    
$fp = fopen ($destination, 'w+');
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );

  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10 );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp );
  curl_exec( $ch );
  curl_close( $ch );
  fclose( $fp );
```

reference
http://www.tricksofit.com/2014/04/download-file-from-remote-server-in-php

Answer (score 4):

[`file_put_contents`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) expects a filename, not a directory name.

Comment: he pass $_url to get_contents. What are you talking about

Comment: Probably a typo. OP is definitely passing just a directory to file_put_contents, which is probably where things are blowing up.

Comment: i think he means `file_put_contents`

Comment: Thanks @Marc B, typo on my part.

Comment: @ceey: you wrote  `*_get_*()` before ;)

Comment: I do have a file name.  `$_dir.$file_name` is a full path to the file name.  `$file_name` is the name of the file which I already extracted from the URL

Comment: @Corey Nice of you to include that code in the original question. *sigh*

Comment: It was there, I just wasn't clear on what my variables were in the original post.

Comment: It may have been in the code, but it certainly wasn't in the question (http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/6348602/1), hence this answer. We can't read your mind.

Comment: Yes I understand that.  What I don't understand is why you're getting so caught up on pointing out minor details.  Especially when they don't help me solve my problem.  If you don't want to help, fine.  But you're wasting my time and yours pointing out irrelevant information

Comment: If your code was actually as originally written, it wouldn't have been a "minor detail", hence the posted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Split it into different stages:

```
$raw = file_get_contents($_url);
... check if $raw has anything useful in it
file_put_contents($_dir, $raw);
... check if the file showed up
```

Either the fetch is failing in file_get_contents, or the write is failing in file_put_contents, or the file you're downloading is too large and exceeds your PHP's default memory_limit.

Comment: At the time I wrote it, there was no extra information. If you're going to be spamming downvotes, at least check that the "wrong" answer comes AFTER  the latest change in the question.

Comment: No, but it helps with diagnosis. Doing it all on one line just give you "x failed on line Y".

Comment: that's enough in this case :) `failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!` anyway i would toggle off my -1 after your comments but 40min were passed already

Answer (score 0):

You may not have fopen wrappers enabled so file_get_contents may not work. Try using [`curl`](http://www.php.net/curl) or a library like [Snoopy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/snoopy/).

Answer (score 0):

With validations...

Validate if file exists first:

```
function doesUrlExists($url) {
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    if($code == 200){
        $status = true;
    }else{
        $status = false;
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    return $status;
}
```

And then put file content (with laravel storage class):

```
 if(!doesUrlExists($url_file)) {
     die('The remote file is not accessible. Please check the URL.');
 }

 Storage::disk('local')
          ->put($file_destintation, fopen($url_file, 'r'));
```