# Manually setting $_FILES values? (Trying to upload from URI and want to use existing code)

Tags: php, file, post, upload

I'm trying to add to Kusaba X, the imageboard script, a way to **upload files from remote locations**.

The class does a lot of checks on `$_FILES['imagefile']['name']` and `$_FILES['imagefile']['size']`, want to reuse them for a file upload from remote URI. In `upload.class.php` I have a variable containing the URI of the pic I want to upload. I don't want to rewrite it all of make a long bunch of if/elses or practically copy that code, was thinking if there was a way to use them as they are?

Tried to ($imgURI is the http:// location of the file):

```
$_FILES['imagefile']['name'] = $imgURI;
```

and

```
$imagefile_name = fopen($imgURI,"rb");
$_FILES['imagefile']['name'] = $imagefile_name;
```

but no luck.

I could make a master variable on which all checks are run and make a big find and replace, but what should it contain?

Hope the question is clear enough, it's been a while since I did any PHP so I might be missing something obvious. Thank you for any ideas/thoughts on this

Answer (score 2):

`$_FILES['imagefile']['name']` contains the name of the file on the client PC, which is usually just used as a hint when naming the permanent file on the local system.  The element of `$_FILES` that contains the name of a file that can be read is `$_FILES['imagefile']['tmp_name']`.

However, this is generally expected to be a local filename. It's usually used in code like `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagefile']['tmp_name'], $permanent_file)`. This is basically just renaming the temporary file, and won't work with a URL.

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely that the $_FILES array will support downloading a remote file. Try using curl to download the file to a temporary location and then specify that in $_FILES array.

[Download Remote File to Server with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348602/download-remote-file-to-server-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
$imagefile_name = fopen($imgURI,"rb");
$_FILES['imagefile']['name'] = $imagefile_name;
```

does open the remote URI, but set a **resource** as file name.

This fails, since is a **file name**.

Save the contents of the remote file to a temporary file and set its name the `$_FILES['imagefile']['name']`.

**Nevertheless, this approach smells:** I won't assume setting **$_FILES['imagefile']** to work in each new version of PHP.