# Upload file from URL

Tags: php, image, forms, file, upload

I've been trying to figure out how to upload a file from a URL using the following code without using a form. In a form I can enter in a URL instead of a local file on the computer and it uploads it, So im guessing its possible?:

example location: http://www.bubblews.com/assets/images/news/521013543_1385596410.jpg

```
if ((isset($_FILES['upload']['name'])) && (substr_count($_FILES['upload']['type'],'image/'))) {

    $prefix = "market/".$market->guid;      
    $filehandler = new ElggFile();
    $filehandler->owner_guid = $market->owner_guid;
    $filehandler->setFilename($prefix . ".jpg");
    $filehandler->open("write");
    $filehandler->write(get_uploaded_file('upload'));
    $filehandler->close();
```

Comment: Sounds like something you should use curl for.

Comment: Downloading a remote file to your server (aka URL upload) is very different from local file upload. A good solution using curl can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348602/download-remote-file-to-server-with-php

Answer (score 5):

Try this example:

[Saving image from PHP URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724391/saving-image-from-php-url-using-php)

```
$ch = curl_init('http://example.com/image.php');
$fp = fopen('/my/folder/flower.gif', 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

or this

```
$url = 'http://example.com/image.php';
$img = '/my/folder/flower.gif';
file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));
```

Answer (score -5):

In linux hosts you can try

```
exec("wget ".$_POST['url']);
```

Comment: Running exec is a really bad idea especially with untrusted post data.

Comment: Very bad.. anyone on the internet could post to that page and force your server to download and execute a malicious file hosted anywhere in the world..

Comment: most of shared hosting doesn't allow exec command

Comment: Very bad advice from a Linux SysAd