# Downloading image from remote link that doesnt end in imagename.ext using PHP

Tags: php, image-processing

Am trying to download an image from remote server and save it in local folder but i cannot seem to find a solution here.  i have seen a couple of similar questions around but mine is a bit unique.

Solutions here are for remote links ending in image name and extension e.g www.example.com/image.jpg mine is a plain url but links to an image whose image type and name is unknown e.g. https://example.com/images/6a9b0547-3d31-4dc9-891c-3ae6ec051056. please help.

Comment: Just use `file_get_contents()` and `file_put_contents()`. Use `finfo` to detect the mime type and name the extension accordingly

Comment: file_get_contents() returns error with file or directory not found

Answer (score 0):

Well, at first you have to download the file to a temporary place. Let's assume you save the file as 399443553.tmp. Use `mime_content_type()` function to get the mime type of the file. At last, move the file to its real location with the extension you got from `mime_content_type()`

[Here](http://php.net/manual/tr/function.mime-content-type.php) is the documentation for `mime_content_type()`

Example from php.net

```
<?php
  echo mime_content_type('php.gif') . "\n";
?>
```

output

```
image/gif
```

PS. Don't be confused about the .gif in the filename. It will return the real MIME type even if it is not there

Comment: this helped, i downloaded the file using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348602/download-remote-file-to-server-with-php and managed to get the extension using your approach... thank you!